# Barplots with percentages of different variables

Tags: r, graph, plot

Given following example:

```
structure(list(jdgcbrbR = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    ctprpwrR = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), hrshsntaR = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), dbctvrdR = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), lwstrobR = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), rgbrklwR = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ctinpltR = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), stcbg2tR = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), tmprsR = c(NA, NA, NA, 0L, 0L, NA, NA, NA
    ), caplcstR = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), widprsnR = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), wevdctR = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("jdgcbrbR", "ctprpwrR", "hrshsntaR", 
"dbctvrdR", "lwstrobR", "rgbrklwR", "ctinpltR", "stcbg2tR", "tmprsR", 
"caplcstR", "widprsnR", "wevdctR"), row.names = 747:754, class = "data.frame")
```

How could I create a set of `barplots`, graphing the percentage of `1-values` in each variable, thus giving a nice overview of the evolution of the percentage of 1's.

So far I tried creating the percentages (which failed because `nrow` is perceived as `NULL`):

```
pct_jdgcbrbR <- (sum(jdgcbrbR) / nrow(jdgcbrbR) * 100)
pct_jdgcbrbR
```

And I found the barplot function which could be usefull:

```
barplot(percentages, main="INR", 
        xlab="varnames")
```

The result should look something like this example I made in Excel:

[image: graph]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works for me, assuming your data.frame is called "temp":

```
barplot((colSums(temp, na.rm=TRUE)/nrow(temp))*100)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works. Could I add an argument to that if I only wanted, say, the last 5 variables in the graph?

Comment: @kwanti, sure. You can just use basic subsetting. For example, to plot just the first, third, and seventh variables, you can use something like `temp[c(1, 3, 7)]` instead of just `temp`.